# Use Azure files without mapping drive or being available publicly?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am wondering if it is possible to make use of Azure File storage without needing to map a drive?  I've like to be able to just access it via UNC from an Azure VM (i.e. \azurefilesip\share name).  I'd like it not to ask for credentials (VM is on a workgroup rather than domain) if possible, and then make sure it isn't publicly accessible via the DNS name.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Created Azure files but I cannot see how to access without inputting credentials and cannot see how to stop it being publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

**By creating private endpoint or using restrict public endpoints access you can stop it being publicly available.**

Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-endpoints?tabs=azure-portal#create-a-private-endpoint) **to create private end point or to restrict public access.**

- Below are the steps to create private end point in storage account.
- Go to your storage a/c >> Networking>> private endpoint connections>>private endpoint.

[image]

- In create a private endpoint basics make sure your region is same for storage a/c and your VN to avoid complexity.

[image]

- Then after basics in resource the **Target sub resource** will be **file**.
  [image]
- Then you need it give your VN and Sub net details and you can select Dynamically/static allocate Ip address. Make sure if you select Statically you need to give the file name and Ip address.
  [image]
  Then in DNS cross check your subscription and resource group and click Review + create to create the private endpoint. By doing this, you can make sure that only traffic coming from the chosen virtual networks may access the Azure file shares that are part of the storage account.
- **Yes, it is possible** to access Azure File storage from an Azure VM using UNC without mapping a drive. To accomplish this, you can access the file share directly from the VM using the UNC path azure-files-ip>share-name>.

  Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#access-an-azure-file-share-via-its-unc-path) **to access an azure file share via it's UNC path.**
- Thanks to @ Adam Bertram for net use command document. You can also use [net use](https://adamtheautomator.com/net-use/) command in your VM to create mapping . There are several ways to accomplish this, including using Windows Explorer, the Command Prompt, PowerShell.